# Environment variable for android

Tags: android

I am trying to update a system that would be able to run android development on eclipse. I installed the `android-sdk` and updated the system path. The path is `"C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools"`. When I give adb in cmd prompt when cmd prompt is `"C:\Users\Darshana"` it says not recognized as an internal or external command.. but when I browse in cmd prompt to `"C:\"`, adb is recognized. It is happening only on 1 system...Can I know the reason?

Comment: describe your question more mr friend

Comment: @GoogleResearcher I think I ve explained my problem clearly enuf...Can I know what more info do u require?

Comment: Usually you should add path to both `platform-tools` and `tools`. Or you can try `where adb` to conform the path

Comment: @YankeeWhiskey Have added both..still the same\

Answer (score 0):

set the environmental path in system properties

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm